# setVisibility() doesn't keep in landscape mode

Tags: android

I created an activity that has a textview (`tv`), a visible button (`advance`) and an invisible button (`next`). when the user clicks on the button, the message and the button become invisible and the button (`next`) appears.

Everything works OK, except for one thing. when I rotate the screen to Landscape mode, the textview and the button "from before" reappear and the `next` button disappear.
What did I miss?

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    }

    Button advance, next;
    TextView tv;

    public void msgClickClose(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        advance = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.msg);
        next = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        advance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a read this article

Comment: Can you explain why you're calling `setContentView` in the `onClick` method?

Comment: @GGWP I tried to make it less complicated, but when the user clicks the button there is also another layout showed by inflater, so when the inflater "done with his job", the current activity supposed to be the main4activity, again.